# Selecting 4 images from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a list of hundred image boxes (50x50 px), and I wanna be able to choose four of them. To check the fifth one, I'd have to uncheck one of the previous ones.

I have found jQuery UI selectable component to do this, I could be able to use ajax to dynamically save information to the database (everything has to be stored in the database here).

The problem is that I couldn't find options to limit selection to 4, and I couldn't find the option to select elements by default after the page is loaded.

How can I do what I want to?

Right now I only have jQuery code:

```
$("#selectable").selectable();
```

An SQL choosing images and simple for loop generating those boxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will limit to the first 4 selections using jQueryUI selectable

```
function clearOverlimitSelections(evt, ui) {

  var selectableClasses = {
      selectableselecting: 'ui-selecting',
      selectableselected: 'ui-selected'
    },
    selectableClassName = selectableClasses[evt.type];

  var $selection = $(this).find('.' + selectableClassName);
  if ($selection.length >= 4) {         
    $selection.filter(':gt(3)').removeClass(selectableClassName)
  }


}

$("#selectable").selectable({
    selecting: clearOverlimitSelections,
    selected: clearOverlimitSelections
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/d5H8PiWgykSyFS0skf7u?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: It still allows me to select just one item at the time though.

Comment: well it's not totally clear what you need, you only said limit to 4

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to select one element, then the second (then both are selected), then third, fourth (four are selected at the same time). And then to select the fifth element, I would have to unselect one of the previous elements.

Comment: if you just want to click then selectable might not be right tool. Requires holding `CTRL` while click individual

Comment: I would want an event on click, to save selected elements to the database, and remove unselected.

Comment: well you can play with mine and if it's not what you need just use clcik handlers

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this:

```
<img class="select-4" ...>
<img class="select-4" ...>
...
<img class="select-4" ...>
```

The following jQuery code should select a maximum of 4 images:

```
$('img.select-4').on('click', function(){
   var iAmSelected = $(this).hasClass('selected');
   if (iAmSelected) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
   } else {
      var canAddSelection = $('img.select-4').length < 4;
      if (canAddSelection) {
         $(this).addClass('selected');
      }
   }
});
```

Then, you can use the `selected` class to style your selected images as you like. The same technique can be used with `<input type="checkbox">` elements.